# Discord.js - Bot repeats the same message edited/deleted log repeatedly

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to create a message logger for my discord bot, that logs edited and deleted messages. However, the log works once, and then stops working. What happens is after it logs one message, the second time it will log 2 of the same, and then 3, and eventually spam the logs with the same message.

Here is my code:

```
client.on("messageUpdate", message => {
  var messages = [1] 
  if(messages.includes(message.id)){return;}
  channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get('channelID')
  const channel9 = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === '816339882233561129');
  const ediembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(1752220)
    .setTitle(":pencil: Message Edited")
    .addFields (
      {name: "__Channel:__", value: `<\#${message.channel.id}>`},
      {name: "__Message Author:__", value: `${message.author.tag} - <\@${message.author.id}>`},
      {name: "__Original Message:__", value: message.content}
        
      )
    .setTimestamp()
    .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL())
    .setFooter("DM reloaded#1269 with any inquiries regarding bot API")
  channel9.send(ediembed)
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue before. When it sends a message it updates and rereads the message and sends the response again I reccomend keeping a array of message id's that it has tracked and check if the message id is already in the array then return like this:
`var messages = []`
`if(messages.includes(message.id)){return;}`

if that doesn't work I'm sorry but I don't know what to do

Comment: Okay, it worked... Somewhat. Now it sends the log once and then kills the script with the following error: 
`RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values may not be empty.`

I've encountered this error previously and have been unable to find a solution. Perhaps you know?

Comment: what code did you add right before the error started occurring?

Comment: This is what it is now: (check updated code above)